# Fullscreen video that allows scrolling

Tags: css, video

I'm working on a site where the first thing the user see is a video. I want that video to be full screen, but to also allow scrolling.

Something like this: http://wearefetch.com/

As you can see, the video is fullscreen but you can also scroll down.

I've searched the web a bit but didn't find anything particularly helpful. If anybody can nudge me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
video#bgvid {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
<source src="polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If screen width is bellow `800px`

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
html { background: url(polina.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; }
#bgvid { display: none; }
}
```

[visit here for more details](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video)

Comment: Hey thanks, it kinda of worked. Still a few minor issues here and there. Thanks again.

Comment: what are minor issue?? which one??

Comment: Well, the video will be cut from the sides if viewing on smaller resolutions, I'll have to see what I can do about that. But then again that's to be expected.

Comment: have you checked link i gave solution for that too

Comment: Yes I did. Solved it now. There was a error in my CSS. Thanks again.